# Rails PrawnPDF same line text align

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I have generated a PDF with the cost of an item on one line. At the moment I just have spaces that just randomly se

```
@reqexpenses.each do |re|
  text "#{re.expense_name}                                                                                                                                        $#{re.cost}"
  move_down 20
  @req_total = @req_total + re.cost
end
```

[image]

If I try to add a right-align in the same line using `:align => :right` it does nothing. Is it possible to do this with Prawn? After browsing the documentation I found no instances of this.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I just ended up doing a table. It's not a very elegant solution but it works.